# How to merge the output of grouped cells?

Tags: output-formatting

I'd like to keep my cells grouped with the output displayed at the end of the group. Is it any way how to suppress the output within each cell and print all evaluated results together at the end of the group?

Comment: Just edit each function/command/assigment one after another in a single cell without an ending semicolon...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?:

```
In[5]:= a=6
Solve[3*i + j == 5&&i>0&&j>0, {i, j},
Integers]
Sin[3 a]

Out[5]= 6

Out[6]= {{i->1,j->2}}

Out[7]= Sin[18]
```

Comment: If you want to avoid  printing the assigments, add a semicolon at the end, i.e., `a=6;`. Then, only the results will be shown.